# Determine whether a shutdown is pending

Tags: windows, shutdown

Windows has the command `shutdown /t` to shutdown or restart the computer after a certain delay. A pending shutdown can be aborted with `shutdown /a`.

But how can I determine whether **and when** a shutdown is currently pending or scheduled, without aborting it?

Comment: Shutdown.exe will record events in the Windows SYSTEM Event log with a Source=User32. When a Shutdown command is issued with a timeout of > 120 seconds, event ID 1074 is logged.

Comment: I can find this message in the event log. But it doesn't say when the restart is scheduled for. It just tells the user and reason.

Comment: You need to know the time of the pending shutdown? Please add this important information to your question (you have just invalidated the answer I was writing :/)

Comment: Anything useful from the `-d` option? [Shutdown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx). Maybe you can find useful the [Shutdown Event Tracker](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753185.aspx).

Comment: I have added the information to the question. `/d` specifies the shutdown reason, which I did. This information was recorded in the event log. But not the timeout from `/t`. Shutdown Event Tracker does not seem to be useful. It does not show the timeout, and it needs to be set up in advance.

Comment: Can't help with the time, but from a [related Q+A on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6156216/2096401) you can _detect_ whether a shutdown is pending... the safest is to run `shutdown /a` which will respond `Unable to abort the system shutdown because no shutdown was in progress.(1116)` and set a non-zero `ERRORLEVEL` if no shutdown is scheduled (or nothing and zero `ERRORLEVEL` if one was).

Comment: Just dumped registry on a Windows 7 box before and after `shutdown /r /t 10000` and there's precious little difference: a shuffling in `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\OpenSavePidlMRU\*`, some bytes tweaked in `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\UserAssist\{CEBFF5CD-ACE2-4F4F-9178-9926F41749EA}\Count`).

Comment: @TripeHound `/a' will **abort** an existing shutdown. The OP doesn't want to do that.

Comment: @DavidPostill  As noted on the linked question, you can also use `shutdown /r /t _large-number_` which will give an error if a shutdown is already pending (and if it wasn't, gives you time to cancel it).

Comment: @TripeHound I know. See my answer ;)

Answer (score 21):

#### How can I determine whether and when a shutdown is currently pending or scheduled, without aborting it?

I don't think it is possible to determine **when** the shutdown will happen.

You can determine **if** a shutdown is scheduled using the following algorithm:

1. Run a "test" shutdown using `shutdown /t xxx` with a **large value for the time**.

   - For Windows 7 or later the maximum time allowed was increased from 600 seconds to 315,360,000 seconds (10 years)
2. If there is **already** a shutdown pending then `shutdown /t xxx` will fail with errorlevel `1190`:

   > A system shutdown has already been scheduled.(1190)
3. If you don't get the above error then you know there was no **previous** shutdown scheduled, so you need to delete the "test" shutdown using `shutdown /a`.

The above can be done in a batch file:

```
@echo off
rem perform a "test" shutdown with a large time
shutdown /t 999999
rem if there is already a shutdown pending then %ERRORLEVEL% will be 1190
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1190 (
  echo A shutdown is pending
  ) else (
  rem cancel the "test" shutdown
  shutdown /a
  echo No shutdown is pending
  )
```

Note:

- I haven't tested the above batch file as I don't wish to shutdown my PC at this time.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [Errorlevel](http://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) - Almost all applications and utilities will set an exit code when they complete/terminate.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [shutdown](http://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html) - Shutdown the computer.

Comment: It instills a great deal of confidence in your code that you haven't dared to run it yourself, even though it is supposed to leave the computer running.

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn I've tested it since I wrote the answer ...

Answer (score 3):

A rather more complicated way of finding out whether or not a shutdown is scheduled is to [debug `winlogon.exe` and check the status of the `ShutdownInProgress` flag](https://web.archive.org/web/20160604093253/http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/windows-nt-6-shutdown-process.html). You'll need [debugging tools for Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20110217084226/http://www.microsoft.com:80/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx).

I haven't tried it but [this MSDN blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20151203220510/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/06/09/how-windows-shuts-down.aspx) explains what happens behind the scenes when Windows shuts down and how to debug `winlogon.exe` (which is the ["user-mode process that handles the task of interactive users logging on and logging off"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-winlogon)). The debugger command to get the status of the flag seems to be:

```
dd winlogon!ShutdownInProgress l 1
01062b3c  00000000
```

If you know how to debug kernel processes in Windows, you could try it out. This [beginner's guide to debugging with CDB and NTSD](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6469/Debug-Tutorial-Part-1-Beginning-Debugging-Using-CD) might help.

Comment: Uhm... Interesting. :-) That will tell me as much as the error message from a probing `shutdown /t 99999`, right?

Comment: @LonelyPixel Right. This method is only for the masochists :)

Comment: strictly speaking, `winlogon.exe` is a user space process, not a "kernel process". It is however a "critical system process" (if it exits unexpectedly, the kernel automatically initiates a reboot). I'm not sure why that link tells you to use a kernel debugger, maybe there is some benefit in doing so (especially given it is a critical system process), but it is still a user-space process

Comment: @SimonKissane Winlogon.exe [is indeed a user-mode process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-winlogon). However, [for the reasons stated here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/when-to-use-this-technique), you would [control user-mode debugging from the kernel debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/controlling-the-user-mode-debugger-from-the-kernel-debugger)